# COUNTIFS with defined ranges from other sheet as arguments and R1C1 notation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm having trouble with a formula (`COUNTIFS`) inside a macro. I want to use two ranges I defined in the `Set ranges` section of the code, and have them as arguments for the `COUNTIFS` formula, and also use the *R1C1* notation. The formula should use the criteria `head1` and `head2` to count values in the ranges `rng1` and `rng2`.

```
Sub Macro1()
    ' Declare variables
    Dim wb1 as Workbook
    Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet
    Dim rng1 as Range, rng2 as Range, rng3 as Range

    ' Set variables
    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1= wb1.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2= wb1.Sheets(2)

    ' Set ranges
    With ws1
        Set rng1 = .Range(.Cells(2, .Cells.Find("head1").Column), .Cells(30,.Cells.Find("head1").Column))
        Set rng2 = .Range(.Cells(2, .Cells.Find("head2").Column), .Cells(30,.Cells.Find("head2").Column))
    End With

    ' Formulas
    With ws2
        .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(4, 4)).FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS(" & rng1.Address & ",R1C," & rng2.Address & ",RC1)"
    End With


End Sub
```

The criterias for the formula are the first row and the first column, as you can see in the `formulas` part of the code. The error I get is runtime 1004: "Application-defined or Object-defined error".

Can you point out what should I do to correct the code?

Comment: Where is `wbRaw` defined? Should that be `wb1` instead?

Comment: Also your range address needs to dictate that you want it in R1C1 Notation: `rng1.Address(1,1,xlR1C1)`

Comment: Should the formula include the sheet name? Or in other words, are you just getting the range addresses from `ws1` but actually using the `COUNTIFS` with ranges from `ws2` only?

Comment: As to what @BigBen stated you probably want: `rng1.Address(1,1,xlR1C1,1)` which will include the workbook and sheet name in the address in R1C1 style.  Or `"'" & ws1.Name & "'!" & rng1.Address(1,1,xlR1C1)`

Comment: `wbRaw` should be `wb1`. @elektrykalAJ is right. @BigBen I thought that by defining the ranges previously I wouldn't have to use the sheet name. I'll try @Scott Craner first solution, otherwise I'll have to use the second one.